# Error registering COM+ application proxy

Tags: vb.net, vb6, com+, dcom

I have exported a COM+ application proxy, which generates MSI and CAB files, and I have successfully installed them on a few different Win XP and Vista machines. However, I have a WinXP box that isn't playing nicely. When I try and run the MSI it gives me the following error message:

"Error registering COM+ Application."

It stops there, not even getting as far as creating the application in COM+. Any ideas on where to look? I'm guessing some dependency is MIA, disabled, or misconfigured, but I can't seem to figure out what's missing from the magic sauce.

Also, if any of you have experience registering the client app proxy manually, that would be swell, too.

peace|dewde

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, this particular error can have many causes, mostly IT-related. Most typically, in my experience, it is permissions issues or a corrupted COM+ installation.

I follow a few basic steps for troubleshooting this generic error.

First, make sure that you can view the COM+ applications (in Component Services) on the box. Sometimes you will get an error trying to navigate to the COM+ applications. Searching on the error message will usually lead to a Technet article that describes how to fix the error.

If you can view the COM+ applications, you'll want to double-check that there isn't already a previous proxy installed. Proxies do not upgrade automatically -- you have to remove the old proxy before a newer one is applied.

If you had a previous proxy, it is possible the files, which are located under the "Common Files" folder, were not properly removed.

Use [ProcMon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to diagnose any permissions errors. I have seen other installers that remove security privileges that are needed to install a COM+ proxy.

You can also generate a log of the MSI installation process. I don't usually find this very helpful, but here is the command-line syntax:

```
msiexec /i MyProxy.msi /l*v ProxySetup.log
```

With this combination of techniques, I have always been able to help our customer service team resolve literally hundreds of proxy installation problems.

Answer (score 1):

Not much help, but try looking in the events log for more information.